# Как отследить нажатие на экран в java если у меня нет View, а объекты я рисую на canvas

Tags: java, android

Как отследить нажатие на экран если у меня не используется Xml и я рисую все на canvas в классе GameView? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что есть GameView? от чего он наследуется?

Answer (score 2):

Можете переопределить метод `onTouchEvent` в `View`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: А куда его присваивать?

Comment: кого присваивать?

Comment: у вас же `class GameView extends View{}`?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `Activity.onUserInteraction()` - работает при любом нажатии в пределах `Activity`, можно также `Activity.onTouchEvent()` - но он вызывается только если не обработано касание в `View` внутри `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Неизвестно что за либа и что с себя представляет GameView, по этому точного ответа не будет. Но если у вас есть доступ к активности тогда вы можете получить доступ и к родительскому View. К примеру

```
getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
```

или

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

или

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()
```

Ну а даль к полученному view добавить ваш слушатель `.setOnTouchListener()`